# How to activate a virtual environment using Python

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv

I am struggling to activate my virtual environment located here `C:\Users\HP\project1_env`.

I have tried the following commands -

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HP>project1_env\scripts\activate

C:\Users\HP>project1_env\scripts\activate.bat

C:\Users\HP>cd project1_env\scripts\activate
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\HP>cd C:\Users\HP\project1_env\Scripts

C:\Users\HP\project1_env\Scripts>activate

C:\Users\HP\project1_env\Scripts>cd C:\Users\HP\project1_env\Scripts\activate
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\HP\project1_env\Scripts>C:\Users\HP\project1_env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

**Update**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HP>project1_env\scripts\activate

C:\Users\HP>project1_env\scripts\activate

C:\Users\HP>python manage.py runserver
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\HP>python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

C:\Users\HP>
```

Comment: What makes you believe it didn't activate (on the first attempt, even)? Are there any error indications?

Comment: When it works properly shouldn't it say - (project1_env) C:\Users\HP\django_project1>

Comment: Run this after activating and see if it prints the expected Python executable inside the VirtualEnv: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`

Comment: I have updated the bottom of my original question.

Comment: You are in the wrong directory. Activating an environment does not necessarily change the directory. You can take a look at this page for a better understanding of virtual envs and such in Python: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/.

Comment: type the command `where python` before typing `activate` and type it after having coalled it you will see whether your virtualenv has been activated sucessfully

Answer (score 0):

You should run `python manage.py runserver` in the directory of your Django project, not where your virtual environment is placed. Try changing directory to where your manage.py file is placed and try again.

Also, to activate your virtual environment, you should run this command: `%PATH_TO_YOUR_VENV_DIRECTORY\Scripts\activate`

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I consider that your project is located in `C:\Users\HP` and from there you should run `project1_env\Scripts\activate` and then move to where your manage.py file is located and run
`python manage.py runserver` if you didn't activate your virtual environment you will get an error saying `Django module is not found error`.

Comment: Please let me know if there are any clarifications.